# Display html content of range or htmlfrag

Tags: javascript, dhtml

Once I create a range how do I display the HTML content of it in Firefox?
`range.toString()` only gives me the text content.  In essence, like innerHTML returns the markup in IE.
Thanks

```
function innerHTML(oTarget, sContent, bAppend){
if (document.getElementById && !document.all) {//is this a non ie browser
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(oTarget, 0);
    range.setEnd(oTarget, oTarget.childNodes.length);
    if (sContent) {//if there is content, save it if not return the content
        var htmlFrag = range.createContextualFragment(sContent);
        if (bAppend != true) {//append or replace
            range.deleteContents();
        }
        oTarget.appendChild(htmlFrag); //add the new html
    } else {
        sContent = range.toString();
    }
} else {
    if (sContent) {
        if (bAppend == true) {
            oTarget.innerHTML += sContent;
        } else {
            oTarget.innerHTML = sContent;
        }
    }
    sContent = oTarget.innerHTML;
}
return sContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is part of the JavaScript standard and is supported by all modern browsers. Your `else` statement (for IE) should work in Firefox as well, as long as `oTarget` is an HTML element object.

Comment: I need the flexibility for oTarget to be anything really. innerHTML runs into snags on non-IE in some cases.  I am hoping someone knows the answer to the range HTML display question.